# How do I enable the Terminal plugin for Pycharm Edu 3.5.1?

Tags: python, shell, terminal, pycharm

Upon visiting JetBrains, they say to enable Terminal plugin but I don't see it in my Pycharm. Its no where to be seen and I am really stuck for a project where I need to use the Terminal.

Answer (score 1):

You need to download the terminal plugin and install it

Download link:
https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9966-native-terminal-plugin

After that, open your pycharm and go to the following page:
File | Settings | Plugins |
click the [Install plugin from disk..] button and install your previous downladed plugin. 
A small black button will appear on the tool bar.

If you did not enable the tool bar, here is the trick: 
View | toolbar
check this toolbar option and the cmd button will be shown on the bar

Hope this will help